# Prototype Ajax.Request only calling the last callback

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, prototypejs, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a userscript for a website that uses Prototype.  Rather than use the GM libs (mainly so I can easily repurpose it for Chrome), I decided to use the already-loaded Prototype functions.

I'm iterating through the rows of a table, each signifying a unique user, by checking for an online status element on their profile page.

```
dom = unsafeWindow; //shortening unsafewindow

console.log("main start");
var rows = dom.$$("#users tbody>tr");
var users = dom.$$("#users tbody>tr .user_avatar");
console.log(rows);
for (var i=0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i];
    var user = users[i];
    new dom.Ajax.Request("/users/" + user["title"] + ".html", { //user["title"] is the username
            method:'get',
            onSuccess:     function(response) {
                                var state = "offline";
                                if (response.responseText.indexOf("now_online") > -1) {
                                    state = "online";
                                }
                                row.childElements()[1].innerHTML += "<br /><b>" + state + "</b>";
                        }, 
            onFailure:    function(request) {
                            row.childElements()[1].innerHTML += "<br /><b>Error</b>";
                        }
        }
    );
}
```

Observing the script executing in Firebug, I see all of the GETs return valid response bodies with a status of 200.  However, "online" only gets displayed in the last row.  It appears as if the callbacks for the previous rows aren't being called.  I have verified this with console.log statements after each line.

I searched and found that there were issues with how FB and Firefox 3.5 handled multiple Ajax.Requests http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=1948.  I upgraded to the most recent beta of Firebug and have the most recent non-beta version of Firefox, and still no dice.  The problem occurs even when I have FB disabled completely.

I'm pretty much drawing a blank at this point, so I'm open to any and all suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: This is a FAQ. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061622/javascript-onclick-anonymous-function-help/1061671#1061671

Comment: Where does the 'element' come from? How was it instantiated?

Comment: Also this - http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/closures-in-javascript/

Comment: @o.k.w: thanks for the catch - element was a result of me moving code from a function back into the main ajax callback.

@Chetan: Thanks for the links, but I don't think this is a closure issue.  I have replaced the contents of the callbacks with console.log statements, and I'm still only seeing the last row getting the callback, despite all the requests being made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using [function.bind()](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind) to set the scope/prepend a variable.

```
        onSuccess:     function(response) {
                            var state = "offline";
                            if (response.responseText.indexOf("now_online") > -1) {
                                state = "online";
                            }
                            arguments[0].innerHTML += "<br /><b>" + state + "</b>";
                    }.bind(this,row),
```

EDIT: or check out [This Way Of Doing It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061622/javascript-onclick-anonymous-function-help/1061671#1061671)

Comment: I can't bind to a function like that. The only binding technique that could possibly work in these circumstances is if I could do ajaxReq.onSuccess.bind(this, row), but the minute I instantiate onSuccess, the request gets made.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand why you can't bind like this; the function "bind" returns a functor, which is exactly what the onSuccess argument is expecting.

Comment: I can't call bind like this function(param) { ... }.bind(scope vars), I get js errors.

Comment: That is very strange, I have used that convention many times with no errors, mind sharing what browser/version this is on?  Also, try surrounding the function declaration with parenthesis to hand-serialize it, e.g. `onSuccess: (function () {}).bind(this,...)`